# Looking for a short story about a girl who can go anywhere without causing suspicion?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading a short story about a girl with an interesting superpower.  She can go anywhere (e.g. any secure facility) without causing suspicion - the people around always take it for granted that she belongs there.

I tried a few Google searches to find the story, but I've had absolutely no results.  Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: Some more information would be useful: do you recall the year you read this? Was it in a magazine or anthology, online or print??

Comment: Sorry, I really don't have more information :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is the short story "Access" by [Andy Weir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andy_Weir), the author of the comic *Casey and Andy* and the novel *The Martian*. You can [read the full text online](http://www.galactanet.com/oneoff/access_mod.html) on Andy Weir's creative writings website.

The girl describes her power like this:

> “As far as I can tell, everywhere I go, everyone thinks I’m *supposed* to be there.”

Comment: This is exactly it!  Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Could it be Imp from the web serial *Worm*?

From the [cast page](https://parahumans.wordpress.com/cast-spoiler-free/cast/):

> Her power renders her unnoticeable, to the point that people she attacks don’t remember she attacked them.

Comment: Please add some reasons why you think this might be the answer.

Comment: Nice update on your answer :) Though it might not be the good answer I dont think this -1 is justifieable since your update. Sorry about that person and I hope it wont scare you away from our community

Comment: Take an upvote. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, upvoted!  Imp definitely has the power I described.  Unfortunately I have a hard time thinking of Worm as a "short story".

Answer (score 1):

I think the other two have it covered, but if it were online fiction, it's also possible that it's [Dorothy Maxwell](http://crystalhall.wikia.com/wiki/Dorothy_Maxwell), a side character in ["*I Looked into the Abyss, and it Winked*"](http://whateleyacademy.net/index.php/content_page/9-original-canon/317-i-looked-into-the-abyss-and-it-winked-part-1), a Whateley Academy story. She has a powerful uncontrolled ESP talent that causes everyone to forget she was there. She can interact with people, but they retain no memory of the encounter.