# 1960s sci-fi novella with a character who is treated as invisible by being ignored

Tags: story-identification, novella

In the late 1960s I read a fascinating science fiction novella - part of a double header paperback series (Ace Doubles books?) - which I have been trying to identify.

The lead male character discovers he can enter rooms etc where he is ignored - treated effectively as invisible. Room occupants give him a cursory look then just ignore him. He can appropriate money - from banks, take food and possessions without suspicion. Eventually he walks unnoticed onto a space ship and continues the adventure on other planets.

Definitely not Niven’s novel *A Gift from Earth*. The action as I remember starts on Earth in the not-too-distant future. Space travel is relatively new. The crime aspect I recall alludes to Silverberg, but he does not have his character sneaking onto a space ship on Earth bound for the planets, which is a strong memory for me.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Fairly sure it was between 1968-71. Bought the paperback second hand in a Forces families shop (SSAFA) in Cyprus. It was one of a double header - the second novel was upside down at the back of the paperback - cannot remember the second title. This seems to be part of the Ace Books Doubles series - but not sure which Series.

Comment: Matthew Keller in [*A Gift from Earth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Gift_from_Earth) (1968; by Larry Niven) has this power, but he does not leave his world for other planets. He does spend time on an old spaceship, though.

Comment: Not this other story then about a girl who can go anywhere without causing suspicion then, because it's from the 2010s: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/78658/4918

Comment: Is the character's invisibility a superpower he has, or is he being ignored as a punishment?

Comment: Lorenzo Smythe in Heinlein's "Double Star" could do that - not some super power, but just a great actor. He just acted (intentionally) as the most boring person the world had ever seen, and people would just ignore him.

Comment: A few years ago, Eric James Stone published a novel called *Unforgettable* in which the hero isn't exactly invisible -- but everybody forgets his existence after going two minutes without seeing him or hearing his voice. This makes it very difficult to maintain any sort of social relationship with anybody, but makes it easy for him to steal things on behalf of the CIA. (Even though his handler keeps forgetting who he is, and needs to consult written notes each time they speak on the telephone.)

Comment: If any of these suggestions seem right, please let us know; the posters will be glad to develop them into answers.  (If these suggestions are wrong, that's also good feedback.)

Comment: @Gaultheria hadn't seen your comment. I too vote for "A Gift from Earth".

Comment: No worries, @LSerni. Thanks. I should have posted my answer sooner, and then deleted it if it turned out to be incorrect, rather than stretching out the process by posting it as a comment first.

Answer (score 13):

**(An update from the original poster confirms that this is not the answer.)**

## [*A Gift from Earth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Gift_from_Earth) (1968), by Larry Niven

Matt Keller has a psychic power that is sometimes useful and sometimes inconvenient: when he feels nervous, people ignore him.  To be affected, people must initially see him, although then they immediately lose interest.  As a boy, the power kept him safe from bullies; as a young man, it interferes with his romantic opportunities.

Matt is one of the underclass on the segregated colony world of Plateau.  He becomes caught up in a revolutionary group infiltrating the privileged class's centre of authority: the two colony ships that brought humans to Plateau.  Matt uses his power to steal supplies, evade capture, and rescue prisoners.

Matt's journey does not literally take him to other worlds, but it does take him to parts of Plateau that are reserved for the ruling class.

You can borrow [*A Gift from Earth*](https://archive.org/details/giftfromearth0000nive) as an e-book from [The Internet Archive](https://archive.org/about/).

[image: Cover: A Gift from Earth]

Answer (score 12):

Was the pseudo-invisibility forced upon him? Robert Silverberg wrote a novella called "To See the Invisible Man" about a protagonist who is sentenced to be invisible. Among other things, he enters women's dressing rooms. The story was based on/inspired by a short story of Borges.

Comment: Here is the ISFDB record for _To See the Invisible Man_. Do any of the book covers look familiar?
http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?59335

Comment: It was also made into an episode of the 1980s *Twilight Zone*:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_See_the_Invisible_Man

Comment: The involvement with crime rings a bell, but the stigmata aspect not. Familiar with Silverberg’s work, but ‘Invisible’ is a short story of about 17 pages and I was fairly sure that the tale I am recalling was longer, and included in Ace Doubles popular ‘tete beche’ series. Also if this is the story then would have to have either the first Galaxy mag issue or one of the ‘Needle in a Timestack’ anthology. Read many, many SF short story compilations around that time - it was a long time ago. Character definite walked aboard a spaceship unnoticed.

Comment: Silverberg's story was also the basis of the Twilight Zone episode of the same name.

Comment: After which short story by Borges is that inspired by?

Comment: Silverberg based it off a line from Borges' "Lottery in Babylon. "

Answer (score 3):

It sounds a lot like Larry Niven's 1986 novel *[A Gift From Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Gift_from_Earth)*, set in his Known Universe future history. It was originally serialized as "Slowboat Cargo". The hero, Matthew Keller, discovers that he has exactly the psychic power you describe. I can't, however, find any evidence that this book was ever published as part of a double.

Comment: Hi. I'm working on a Niven answer right now to go along with my comment from a few hours ago.

Comment: Definitely not Niven’s piece. The action As I remember starts on earth in the not too distant future. Space travel is relatively new. The crime aspect I recall alludes to Silverberg but he does not have his character sneaking onto a space ship on earth bound for the planets which is a strong memory for me.

Comment: ...and thanks for all the suggestions, guys. Sure I will get it. But remember, it MUST be published before 1972.