# Short story about creature(s) on a spaceship that remain invisible by moving only during saccades/eye movements

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

They cause some sort of trouble or mischief, and one of the crew catches on and devises a way to catch it (or one of them). My Google-fu has failed me on this one.

Additional info:

- Strong feeling that this was a short story
- Likely a prolific writer from the 50s-60s that I found on Project Gutenberg
- Not Peter Watts' Blindsight, though that returns the most hits on searches
- Don't recall what the creatures did that was problematic, but one of the (two-man?) crew puzzled it out from clues and caught it maybe by anticipating its moves. It's fuzzy, so don't get hung up on this bullet point's contents.

Comment: It's not Larry Niven's A Gift From Earth, is it? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/213324/1960s-sci-fi-novella-with-a-character-who-is-treated-as-invisible-by-being-ignor

Comment: @BenCrowell, no, the gimmick in A Gift from Earth is a simple "I'm not interesting" psychic field.  Very different invisibility mechanism (and also not a short story).

Comment: I doubt it was original, but the Dr Who (Matt Smith, approx 2013) adversary of 'Weeping Angels' had that characteristic.

Comment: @eBox Would not surprise me if the Weeping Angels were inspired by that story, but the description doesn't fit at all with them. Weeping Angels were described as "quantum locked" meaning they could only move (but move very fast) while unobserved - they were always visible, and observer eye movement was irrelevant. The "don't blink" admonition was because they could cover a lot of ground in the fraction of a second a person's gaze is interrupted by an eye blink.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This answer does **not** match your main point about moving during saccades, but all of your secondary points (short story about an 'invisible' creature on a spaceship, prolific 50s-60s author, two-man crew, Project Gutenberg ...) reminded me of [*All Cats Are Grey*](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/29019/29019-h/29019-h.htm) by Andre Norton:

> it’s invisible because it’s a color beyond our range of sight

One of the protagonists and her cat are colour-blind but

> he [the cat] can see above and below our range of color vibrations and—apparently—so can I!

The protagonist destroys the creature by seeing the cat react, placing a piece of clothing as a background to make the creature's movements visible, then blasting it:

> I waited to see that flicker against the spaceall and then I let him have it

(I have [mixed up plot points in a story-ID question myself in the past](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72293/story-on-forest-timescale) so I thought this was worth a shot ...)

Comment: The title, the author, some key plot points, and the general tone/style are all familiar and spot on. Other parts of the story seem fresh to me, but I'll chalk that up to faulty memory. I think you got it! Thank you!

Comment: "it’s invisible because it’s a color beyond our range of sight" it would be pitch black to us in reality, I think? Because "color" is what body reflects/emits, and it wouldn't do either within visible spectrum.

Answer (score 21):

Are you sure it was a short story? That’s a plot element of Peter Watts’ novel *[Blindsight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blindsight_(Watts_novel))*, with the extremely alien scramblers able to fool human neurology in a number of ways, of which movement during saccades is one.

Comment: Not Blindsight--haven't read that but it's on my list now :)  I feel pretty sure it was a short story. In my memory it has the feel of 60s scifi, one of the prolific writers like Harry Harrison, but I didn't find a good candidate when reviewing the list of his titles.